# Fire one event after all 'change' events

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a dynamic form with elements loaded in and out at various points. Form elements also update other elements' values on-the-fly. To handle this, I have a change event bound to all `select` and `input` elements using:

```
jQuery('#myelement').on('change', 'select,input', function(e){
    // ... do things after any form element changes value

    // Fire myFunction() only once - preferably after the final 'change' event happens.
    myFunction();
});
```

I now need a single callback to fire after all change events trigger. Placing anything inside my bound event will trigger after any element value changes. I want to instead only trigger my callback once. How can I do that?

---- Edit ----

I guess I am not clear in what I am asking.

I have an element, let's call it `#myelement` (whether it's a form or not is irrelevant). I have some code that runs when the page is ready that binds some change events to children of `#myelement`, as shown in the code above. I do this because I have components being loaded dynamically, and simple `('select').on('change', function() ...` does not bind to new form elements.

When a form element changes, there are additional custom events that will fire for each one. Some of them follow up by firing `(#another-element).trigger('change')`. The number of change events that trigger after one element's value changes could be zero or it could be ten. When all is said and done, I want a spot where I can call a single method that will fire one time after all these change events that are queued up happen.

The next time an element's value changes, I will want to fire this again, once, after all subsequent change events happen.

I can't really be any clearer than that. I suppose another way of wording it would be, how can I determine the number of change events that will trigger in this case?

---

*Glossary*

1. Final Change Event - the final change event in a queue of change events. If you say `jQuery('select').on('change', function(){ ... })`, the final change event will be the event triggered on the last `select` element in the queue.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "after all change events trigger"? Are you looking for something like the  [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method?

Comment: Is there an exact point when everything finishes?

Comment: @Vohuman I need a single function to trigger one time only after all change events on the page have occurred.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the question correctly you want to have a callback function which is executed when all the form elements have been changed. As far as I know there is no such event. You can store the changed form controls in an array and compare the length of the array against the length of the form controls:

```
var 
    $form = $('#my-form'),
    // the following variables should be reset
    // when the form controls are regenerated
    changedElements = [], 
    formControlsLength = $form.prop('elements').length
;

$form.on('change', 'input, select', function() {
    if ( changedElements.indexOf(this) !== -1 ) return;
    changedElements.push(this);
    if ( changedElements.length === formControlsLength ) {
       $form.trigger('all_changed');
    }
});

$form.on('all_changed', function() {
   // ...
});
```

Another way of implementing the same logic is using CSS classes:

```
$form.on('change', 'input, select', function() {
    var $els = $($form.prop('elements'));
    $(this).addClass('changed');
    if ( $els.not('.changed').length === 0 ) {
       $form.trigger('all_changed');
    }
});
```

Comment: This was pretty much the thought I was exploring. I was trying to find a way to determine when the final `change` was called, I figured there was a way to do that without having to count elements and compare it to the number of changes that have triggered. I guess what I need is something such as `afterAllEvents('change')`

Comment: You're adding the `changed` class to `$(this)` but shouldn't you be adding it to the form element instead?

Comment: @pspahn No. The class is added to changed control. When all of them have `change` class, the event is triggered.

Comment: This assumes that every form element will change, does it not? The number of elements in the form and the number of change events are not related.

Comment: @pspahn Have you tried the code? How exactly "The number of elements in the form and the number of change events are not related"? Don't you want to execute some code when all the form elements are changed?

Comment: I guess I'm not following. You seem to be comparing the number of elements in the form (let's say 10) and checking to see when they all have a `.changed` class. Not all form elements will change, so `$els.not('.changed').length` will never be zero.

Comment: Really, all I want is a way to determine when the final `change` event happens. I figured the easiest way would be to just look at the events, count how many will trigger, then run something when it gets there. Is it possible to just count the `change` events?

Comment: Define "final change event". And yes, you can count them. `var i = 0` and in your handler `i++` and then `if ( i === yourCriterion )`

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I can see my question is not being understood correctly.